Can't Tile Windows after macOS reinstall
I recently had to reinstall macOS (Sonoma) on my M3 MacBook Pro and I no longer have the option to Tile windows to either side of the screen. This option has been replaced by Move Window to X Side of Screen, as show in the screenshot below. This applies to all apps. What is going on and how to I get this functionality back? I can't seem to find anything related to this issue anywhere.


Is that specific to iTerm, or are all windows displaying the same?

@MarcWilson Yes, all apps, Apple and third-party.

I found out what is going on: though I only use the built-in monitor on my MacBook, I had turned on the setting in System Settings →  Desktop & Dock → Mission Control for Displays have separate spaces.
Once I turned it back off and logged in/out I am able to tile windows again!

